# I am getting: "You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'OrdID' as part of an aggregate function. How do I bypass?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010, aggregate-functions

My code is as follows:

```
SELECT Last, OrderLine.OrdID, OrdDate, SUM(Price*Qty)  AS total_price
    FROM ((Cus INNER JOIN Orders ON Cus.CID=Orders.CID)
        INNER JOIN OrderLine
            ON Orders.OrdID=OrderLine.OrdID)
        INNER JOIN ProdFabric
            ON OrderLine.PrID=ProdFabric.PrID   
            AND OrderLine.Fabric=ProdFabric.Fabric  
    GROUP BY Last  
    ORDER BY Last DESC, OrderLine.OrdID DESC;
```

This code has been answered before, but vaguely.  I was wondering where I am going wrong.

> You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'OrdID' as part of an aggregate function.

Is the error message I keep getting, no matter what I change, it gives me this error.  Yes I know, it is written as SQL-92, but how do I make this a legal function?

Comment: You need to `group by` each one of the non-aggregated columns... Any basic SQL tutorial can tell you this and more.

Comment: Would this work in MySQL ?

Answer (score 10):

For almost every DBMS (MySQL is the only exception I'm aware of, but there could be others), every column in a `SELECT` that is not aggregated needs to be in the `GROUP BY` clause. In the case of your query, that would be everything but the columns in the `SUM()`:

```
SELECT Last, OrderLine.OrdID, OrdDate, SUM(Price*Qty)  AS total_price
...   
GROUP BY Last, OrderLine.OrdID, OrdDate  
ORDER BY Last DESC, OrderLine.OrdID DESC;
```

Comment: in regards to this, it is now telling me that the OrdID could refer to more than one table. i am ripping my hair out!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Sorry. I have a typo (`,` instead of `.`). See my edited `GROUP BY` statement. (You really should take a tutorial or buy a book on SQL; you should have been able to spot that yourself.) :-)

Comment: LOL i kid you not, i am a bum and kept clicking into an old query i hadn't closed.

Answer (score 2):

If you **have** to keep your `GROUP BY` intact (and **not** to add non-agreggated fields to the list) then you need to decide which values you will want for `OrderLine.OrdID` and `OrdDate`.  For example, you may chose to have `MAX` or `MIN` of these values.

So it's either as *bernie* suggested `GROUP BY Last, OrderLine.OrdID, OrdDate` or something like this (if it makes sense for your business logic):

`SELECT Last, MAX(OrderLine.OrdID), MAX(OrdDate),  SUM(Price*Qty)  AS total_price`

Comment: and i tried this, but i need a minimum of 4 results (my 4 order id's) and an order total

Comment: @user2225611 - Are you saying that you need to show individual IDs with with the **same total price** on every line?