# How to display database column value when grouping in query?

Tags: sql, winforms, select

```
select Gender, count(Gender) as Gen, Cost 
from (select  Gender from tbl )
group by Gender 
order by Gender
```

This query is displaying grouped data but not displaying Cost. How to display Cost when grouping?

Comment: Does cost exist in tbl?

Comment: Yes, cost is in database

Comment: You have not selected Cost. try select  Gender,cost from tbl

Comment: Remove the subquery so it is `Cost FROM tbl group by...`

Comment: I need subquery to group data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had you try Sum()?

```
select Gender, count(Gender) as Gen, sum(Cost) as Total
from tbl
group by Gender
order by Gender
```

Answer (score 0):

You must include cost as apart of an aggregate function see this explanation: 
[I am getting: "You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'OrdID' as part of an aggregate function. How do I bypass?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15710741/i-am-getting-you-tried-to-execute-a-query-that-does-not-include-the-specified)

```
select Gender, count(Gender) as Gen, Cost 
from (select  Gender, Cost from tbl )
group by Gender, Cost
order by Gender
```

Comment: This query showing error "You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'Cost' as part of an aggregate function".

Comment: @jarlh is correct one of the only dbms that you can bypass this in is MySQL, I will edit my answe to reflect